# Porting an old cuda code to 7.5

Tags: cuda

An old source code which is compatible with cuda 3.5 is not compatible with newer cuda version, e.g. 7.5. For example,

```
cuda_runtime_api.cc: In function ‘cudaError_t cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const char*, const void*, size_t, size_t, cudaMemcpyKind)’:
cuda_runtime_api.cc:556:141: error: declaration of C function ‘cudaError_t cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const char*, const void*, size_t, size_t, cudaMemcpyKind)’ conflicts with
__host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const char *symbol, const void *src, size_t count, size_t offset, enum cudaMemcpyKind kind)
                                                                                                                                         ^
In file included from cuda_runtime_api.cc:155:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:4335:39: error: previous declaration ‘cudaError_t cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const void*, const void*, size_t, size_t, cudaMemcpyKind)’ here
 extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const void *symbol, const void *src, size_t count, size_t offset __dv(0), enum cudaMemcpyKind kind __dv(cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

So, that says the cudaMemcpyToSymbol() from the code is not compatible with the 7.5 implementation. The source code is

```
__host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const char *symbol, const void *src, size_t count, size_t offset, enum cudaMemcpyKind kind)
{....}
```

and the 7.5 version at /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h is

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const void *symbol, const void *src, size_t count, size_t offset __dv(0), enum cudaMemcpyKind kind __dv(cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

How can I fix that?

UPDATE: The `cuda_runtime_api.cc` in the error file points to a user defined one which is available [here](https://gem5-gpu.cs.wisc.edu/repo/benchmarks/libcuda/file/c59bb5937ef9/cuda_runtime_api.cc#l556).

```
mahmood@u1604:~/gem5-gpu/benchmarks/libcuda$ g++ -std=c++0x -O3 -g -Wall -fPIC  -DCUDART_VERSION=7050 -I./ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I../../gem5/util/m5 -c cuda_runtime_api.cc -o cuda_runtime_api.o
cuda_runtime_api.cc: In function ‘cudaError_t cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const char*, const void*, size_t, size_t, cudaMemcpyKind)’:
cuda_runtime_api.cc:556:143: error: declaration of C function ‘cudaError_t cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const char*, const void*, size_t, size_t, cudaMemcpyKind)’ conflicts with
 __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const char *symbol, const void *src, size_t count, size_t offset , enum cudaMemcpyKind kind )
                                                                                                                                            ^
 In file included from cuda_runtime_api.cc:155:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:4335:39: error: previous declaration ‘cudaError_t cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const void*, const void*, size_t, size_t, cudaMemcpyKind)’ here
 extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const void *symbol, const void *src, size_t count, size_t offset __dv(0), enum cudaMemcpyKind kind __dv(cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
                                   ^
```

Comment: Instead of providing the name of the symbol in ASCII, simply pass the symbol itself.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand that. If you mean I have to change `const char *symbol` to `const void *symbol`, then that doesn't work

Comment: Instead of passing  "a", simply pass `a`.

Comment: If you mean `const char symbol`, that also doesn't work. Sorry but I don't understand why you express that in such an unusual way.

Answer (score 1):

Following comments, the symbol itself has to be passed, not its name in a string. Here is an illustration example on how to use this new API signature:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__constant__ int a[1];

__global__ void kernel()
{
    printf("a = %d\n", a[0]);
}

int main()
{
    int value = 42;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(a, &value, sizeof(int));
    kernel << <1, 1 >> > ();
    return cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

It should print

```
a = 42
```

Comment: So, you are talking about the caller. However, it seems that the problem is something else. I checked one of the calls. In a `.h` file, I see `__constant__ int jds_ptr_int[5000];`. Then in the `.cu` file, I see `cudaMemcpyToSymbol(jds_ptr_int, h_ptr, depth*sizeof(int));`

Comment: The error refers to one of the library files in the old code. Please see the updated post.

Comment: @mahmood, you seem to be having two conflicting symbol declarations in your source file. including some version of headers and redeclaring the same C symbols with a different signature will issue an error. You may want to update your source file accordingly (commenting-out the line with `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`. Though, this is more a C/C++ question than a CUDA question. Finally, please provide a complete minimal reproducer sample.